# I cannot display google map markers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, google-maps-markers

I cannot display google map markers on map. What's wrong? it is been a day :( Am I doing something wrong? please help It is really annoying and I am newbie to angular. I am able to display complete map but markers are not displayed :(

```js
var appa = angular.module('appa',['firebase','uiGmapgoogle-maps']);

appa.controller('mainCtrl', function($firebaseObject,$scope) {
  const rootRef =  firebase.database().ref();
  this.object = $firebaseObject(rootRef);
$scope.markers = [];
var mark =
 {
            lat: 51.2019053,
            lng: 4.404418,
            message: "I want to travel here!",
            focus: true,
            draggable: false
};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker(mark);
$scope.markers.push(marker);
console.log(mark);
  $scope.map = {
    center:
    {
      latitude: 51.219053, longitude: 4.404418 },
     zoom: 14
              };

    });
```

```html
<body ng-app="appa">
    <div id="map_canvas" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <ui-gmap-google-map center="map.center" zoom="map.zoom">
    <marker>
        <marker ng-repeat=" pos in markers" position="{{pos.lat}},{{pos.lng}}"></marker>

                    </ui-gmap-google-map>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Totally not an expert on this but ...
According to https://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/#!/api/marker should you use <ui-gmap-marker /> and not <marker /> and even if there is such a thing as <marker /> it looks like you have an open tag for marker with another open tag inside but this time close. I am referring to this part:

```
<marker>
<marker ng-repeat=" pos in markers" position="{{pos.lat}},{{pos.lng}}"></marker>
```

should't this be just:

```
<marker ng-repeat=" pos in markers" position="{{pos.lat}},{{pos.lng}}"></marker>
```

or according to the docs:

```
<ui-gmap-marker
    idKey='{expression}'
    coords='{expression}'
    click='{expression}'
    options='{expression}'
    events='{expression}'
    control='{expression}'
    >
</ui-gmap-marker>
```

?

Comment: while debugging I just added one extra marker tag. even removing that did not work. I already tried and tried again as said using ui-gmap-marker tag. Still did not make ANY difference. I appreciate help but please help some . I am badly stuck

Comment: okay in a minute i am giving you the link . please give me 1 minute

Comment: Well ... I don't know how to say this to you ... but I can see the marker :D .. just move the map down a bit.

Comment: this is something wierdo. Let me check more :(

Comment: I can not SEE.  what could be wrong ?? I am using linux ubuntu.  Firebase server :( chromium browser

Comment: What I did was to save you HTML and app.js localy .. and open the HTML - the plnkr doesn't work and: http://pl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2s9zvjp&s=9